# How to import new library in Android studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to use [this](https://github.com/pi-null-mezon/vpglib) library in Android Studio.
I'm learning how to use Android and searching on stackflow I've found some solution but not working for me.
Somebody suggest add it from File->Project Structure-> Dependencies
Someboby suggest add it from build.grandle
My question is:
Could I add and use that library or need I anotherone?
I'm using Windows 10.
Following more info about Android Studio version:
[Android version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvjue.png)

Comment: do you want to add library from github? or local ?

Comment: which is the best way?

Comment: I will add a solution for both ways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to import a library from GitHub (Detailed Steps):**

1-Find Your Desired Library, for example, this library : [Example Library](https://github.com/Badranh/Android-Mac-Address-Util)

2- Go to jitpack.io and enter the link of the library and click lookup

3-You will be represented for different versions , usually we choose the latest since it is the better

4- Click on Get it

5- scroll down and follow the given steps which are adding

```
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

to your root build.gradle at the end of repositories.After adding it , it should be like

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

6- Add the given dependency in the other build.gradle(app level) file in dependecies section , for our example jitpack.io has given us this

```
        implementation 'com.github.Badranh:Android-Mac-Address-Util:0.1.0'
```

7-Click on sync now and after it finishes you will be able to use the library

**How to import a local library:**

1-The local library might be the library you downloaded it from the internet or you did it

2-to import it, click on File -> New -> Import Module and then select the library folder

3-Right-click your app in project view and select "Open Module Settings"

4-Right-click your app in project view and select "Open Module Settings"

5-Click the "Dependencies" tab and then the '+' button

6-Select "Module Dependency"

7-Select Library you just imported it and add it

8-Wait for Android Studio To finish and then you can use it

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is C++ library

please go through the link this may help you how to import and use it

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

also there are samples if you want to work with ndk

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk